# custom currency based on sku - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

is there a hook/filter that could be applied so that a products SKU can signify the currency to be used? .e.g. to keep it simple, lets say the SKU is the currency. So if I have an SKU of `USD`, is there a way to make the cart/checkout/order have the `_order_currency` set to USD? It would be awesome if it can also show this on the product catalog/page too.

Comment: When the convertion will happen? in the checkout? in the cart? what will happen when two products with different SKU-Currency are in the cart?

Comment: @Syntax_Error you can only checkout with one specific product at a time...

And no conversion, it would just replace the current nomenclature of the default currency